add Laravel WHERE clause combined from two tables
i am very new to laravel and need help to add one more WHERE into the query
i want to add    ->where('trade_point', '>=', 'points_required')
the trade_point field is in table premiums and points_required field is in table user_premiums
here is my command bellow in /app/Console/Commands/
i have tried this
$premiums = Premium::select(DB::Raw('*'))
    ->Join('user_premiums', 'user_premiums.premium_id', '=', 'premiums.id')
    ->where('premiums.status',  '=', 'running')
    ->where('premiums.date',  '<=', now())
    ->where('user_premiums.points_required', '>=', 'user_premiums.trade_point')
    ->orderBy('premiums.id', 'DESC')
    ->get(); 

it does not give any error and logs Premiums marked as completed and transactions processed successfully but do nothing on database
namespace App\Console\Commands;

use App\Models\Premium;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class MarkPremiumsComplete extends Command
{
  
     protected $signature = 'premiums:mark-as-complete';
    

 
    protected $description = 'Mark premiums as complete';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.

     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
    
     */
    public function handle()
    {
            

          
        $premiums = Premium::with('user_premiums')
        
        ->whereDate('date', '<=', now())
        ->where('status', 'running')
        ->get(); 


        DB::beginTransaction();

        try {
            foreach ($premiums as $premium) {
                foreach ($premium->user_premiums as $prem) {
                    $user = User::find($prem->user_id);
                    $totalPremium = $premium->amount * $prem->trade_point;

                    $user->transactions()->create([
                        'amount' => $totalPremium,
                        'type'   => 'premium',
                        'status' => 'approved',
                    ]);

                    $user->increment('trades_premium', $totalPremium);
                    $user->increment('total_balance', $totalPremium);
                }

                $premium->update(['status' => 'completed']);

                \Log::info('Premiums marked as completed and transactions processed successfully.');
            }

            DB::commit();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            DB::rollBack();
            \Log::error('Error '. $e->getMessage());
        
            return 1; // Return error status code
        }

        $this->info('Premiums marked as completed and transactions processed successfully.');
        return 0; // Return success status code
    }
}


Have you registered this command in app/console directory?which version of laravel you are using?How did you execute your command??

command is registered and works smoothly  i just want to add a condition  to check if table2.points_required >= table2.trade_point it gives error points_required column not found in table1 means my code is not checking the condition of table2


i want to add ->where('trade_point', '>=', 'points_required') the trade_point field is in table premiums and points_required field is in table user_premiums

As per your above stated condition your query that I given below would not work,because the 3rd where clause of the query is not correct. Check that.
Also correct these following section in your query..
-> it should be raw & join not Raw & Join.
-> When you compare two column in query it should be whereColumn not where.
$premiums = Premium::select(DB::Raw('*'))
    ->Join('user_premiums', 'user_premiums.premium_id', '=', 'premiums.id')
    ->where('premiums.status',  '=', 'running')
    ->where('premiums.date',  '<=', now())
    ->where('user_premiums.points_required', '>=', 'user_premiums.trade_point')
    ->orderBy('premiums.id', 'DESC')
    ->get();

Instead try this..
$premiums = DB::table('premiums')
            ->join('user_premiums','premiums.id','=','user_premiums.premium_id')
            ->where('premiums.status',  '=', 'running')
            ->where('premiums.date',  '<=', Carbon::now())
            ->whereColumn('premiums.trade_point','>=','user_premiums.points_required')
            ->select('premiums.*','user_premiums.your-selected-filed','user_premiums.your-selected-field')
            ->orderBy('premiums.id', 'DESC')
            ->get();

N:B :-
1. place use Carbon\Carbon; to the top of the script.
2. placed the proper column in 'user_premiums.cloumn'
of select section of the query to fetch the desired data from the result-set.
Try this,I think it will work.

Thanks for your comment and making me aware about drawing special attention to all the points that went wrong in the query. I have pointed out and updated post.
